# UITableViewCell: Accessory View going away when selected

Tags: objective-c, accessoryview, uitableview

I might be going about this all wrong, so hopefully someone will tell me what I should be doing.

I have constructed a table view to act as a legend and color picker.  In the AccessoryView slot, I places a custom view that is just a colored box.  User will show the legend, so they know what colors mean what, and they can pick on a color to then 'colorize' a drawing by assigning that color to objects.  All of that works just fine.

What I'm having a problem with is the selected row style.  When I select a row from the legend, the cell goes blue, like it should, but my AccessoryView has now disappeared.  I don't want this to happen.  However, I don't know what to set to make it not disappear.  Keep in mind, I still want a row to show up as 'selected'.  But any way that I do that, my accessory view disappears (most likely is hidden by the selected color).

Here's how I'm setting the accessory view right now.

```
CGRect colorBox = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
UIView *colorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:colorBox];
colorView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:[selOption valueForKey:@"qoColor"]];
cell.accessoryView = colorView;
```

Comment: You are using code like `cell.accessoryView = myColorBox;` to set the accessory, right?

Comment: You're not doing anything obviously wrong. Are you using a stock UITableViewCell or a custom subclass? Try creating a minimal project that just puts a custom accessoryView in a table, and see if that has the same problem.

Comment: where do you set the accessory view? that might be the issue

Comment: I set the accessory view in the Table View's tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath, where the cell is being added.  And this is a stock UITableViewCell where I'm setting the cell's TextLabel and AccessoryView.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a UIImageView instead of a UIView, which won't disappear when the cell is selected. You can either make tiny .png thumbnails for each color (if there aren't a lot) or you can create them dynamically in your cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method, ala:

```
UIImageView *colorView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 30.0f, 30.0f);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[self colorWithHexString:[selOption valueForKey:@"qoColor"]]; CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[colorView setImage:image];

[cell setAccessoryView:colorView];
[colorView release];
```

Comment: Why is it that when you use UIImageView it won't disappear, in contrast with UIView?